# Lightning - Server Response SUCCESS

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here's my simple requirement customer is entering customer id in the form, and I am comparing customer id in my database. If customer id is there it should insert a new record and redirect to a new page, if the customer id is not there in my database it should throw an error. Currently the server is giving 'SUCCESS' response instead of 'ERROR' even though the customer is entering an invalid customer id, why so?, appreciate your help.

```
handlClick : function(component, event, helper) {
     var ObjectWith5Fields = component.get("v.deal");
    var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");
    action.setParams({
        "itemd" : ObjectWith5Fields
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log(state);
        if( state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (event.getSource().get("v.name") == 'save'){
                component.set("v.successMessage",true);
            }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                             errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    } );
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

APEX CLASS::

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string saveRecord(Deal__c itemd){
   
     map<string,string> info = new map<string,string>();
        List<Account> results = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Customer_ID__c = : itemd.Customer_ID__c];
        if (results.size() != 0){
            itemd.Account__c  = results.get(0).id;
            
               try{  
        insert itemd;
        //return itemd.id;
        info.put('status','success');
        info.put('message',itemd.id);
    }catch(exception e) {
        system.debug('-------getMessage-----------'+e.getMessage());
        
    } 
        }
    else {
        //return itemd.Customer_ID__c+' is not a valid Customer Account ID.'; 
        info.put('status','error');
        info.put('message',itemd.Customer_ID__c+' is not a valid Customer Account ID.');
    }
        return JSON.serialize(info);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ERROR" state is only given if you get an uncaught Exception.

## Option 1

You can check the return value to see if your custom "error" was returned:

```
if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
  let returnValue = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
  if(returnValue.status === 'success') {
    component.set("v.successMessage",true);
  } else {
    // error condition
    console.log(returnValue.message);
  }
}
if(state === 'ERROR') {
  console.log(response.getError());
}
```

...

## Option 2

Or, you can change your Apex to send an error:

```
 throw new AuraHandledException(itemd.Customer_ID__c+' is not a valid Customer Account ID.');
```

In which case, your current code would be able to identify the error returned.